# how to access or open themes and battery-saver settings windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

hi I've seen the [Uri Schemes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662937%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to open the windows phone settings in the device.

There many other settings in the windows phone like,

Batterysaver,

Themes,

Brightness,

InternetSharing and so on.

how to give link to open those settings in windows phone 8.

Comment: Answer's simple - it's not possible.

Comment: @MarcinJurazek is there any specific reason for not able to access those settings, because they let access to other settings like network settings, lockscreen settings, etc.,

Comment: Here's the uservoice page to vote for more settings URIs. https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-app-platform/suggestions/3484990-more-uri-schemes-for-launching-system-settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No built in way has been provided to launch these settings from within an app.

I would expect that this is due to the excepted use of these features.

I would expect battery saver settings to be changed very infrequently. Turn on "battery saver when low" once and then forget about that setting forever after.

Even if the user changed their theme while the app was in use, the changes wouldn't be applied until the app was restarted. Therefore making a change to the theme and then backing out of the settings page would leave the app still showing the old theme settings. This could be very misleading to the person using the phone as to whether the change was made or not. 
I also expect that people don't change their theme very often.

Why features are or are not included is purely speculative but it all comes down to priorities. If they waited until EVERY feature was added it would never ship.
And on a related note, Microsoft do not talk about unreleased features and future versions so there is no way of knowing if these will come in a future update.